# How can I access values from a key that stores more than one value in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

My dictionary looks like this:

```
{James: [10, 7, 9], 'Bob': [3, 8, 4], 'Charles': [6, 2, 5]}
```

What I want to do is, output each user's score in order of who got the highest score. And with their name. At the moment, I am only able to print the student with the highest score:

```
inverse = [(value, key) for key, value in score_dict.items()]

print (max(inverse)[1])
```

The output is:

```
James
```

The output that I am trying to get is:

```
James 10

Bob 8

Charles 6
```

Comment: `print ("\n".join(inv[1] for inv in sorted(inverse)))`

Comment: Word for the future: It seems like you don't want to *remove* a value from the key, but instead you want to *access* it. If you *remove* a value it's no longer in the list, but if you *access* it you just get its value and leave it in the list. I've put in an edit for you.

Comment: Do you want to store the highest score of each person to a new dictionary or something, or do you just want to print the highest score for each person? Because for the latter you can simply do `for k, v in score_dict.items(): print(k, max(v))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a list of tuples with userwise highscore and later sort it with score. Something like this,

```
x = {'James': [10, 7, 9], 'Bob': [3, 8, 4], 'Charles': [6, 2, 5]}
y = [(k, max(v)) for k, v in x.items()]
for k, v in sorted(y, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
    print (k, v)
```

Comment: Thank you @Muctadir ! It works. However, would you please comment it so that I am sure about what is happening in each line especially line 3. Why are so many variables being created?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your inverse dictionary at all; you're not trying to find *the* single highest score among *all* of the students; instead, you want to find the highest score for *each* student.

To do so, do the following:

```
scores = {'James': [10, 7, 9], 'Bob': [3, 8, 4], 'Charles': [6, 2, 5]}
for name in scores.keys:
    print(name + " " + str(max(scores[name])))
```

This avoids the need for a new dictionary. The most complex part of this is `str(max(scores[name]))`, which, reading from innermost to outermost: "Take name, find name's list of scores, find the max value in their scores, and then turn that into a string".

Comment: I am trying to find the highest score for each student. And because the data has been put into a dictionary from a file (that has been converted to a csv file), the file is not 'suscriptable'

Comment: I believe my code sample *does* return the highest score for each student... And I don't believe I understand what you mean by 'not suscriptable'. Please elaborate? If the file is already in a dictionary, I'm not sure why it affects my code sample.